# Jquery 1.7.1 causing errors in firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug

I am using jquery 1.7.1 (minified). I keep getting an error in firebug: Syntax error,

```
unrecognized expression: > /Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js  Line 3.
```

I have tried using the CDN and receive the same error.

When I try the unminified version, I also get an error: Syntax error,

```
unrecognized expression: > /Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js Line 4179.
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: What code of your own are you including in the page that uses jQuery?

Comment: @user1189847 See if you can get a full stacktrace for the error?

Comment: Have you tried just linking to the jQuery file without adding any of your own JS to see if the error is entirely contained within that version of jQuery?

Comment: That was it, I took out my other JS file and firebug didn't throw any errors. Not sure why I didn't try that to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, try to include with the right order. First include the jquery library and then all the other js files. I hope that's the case :)

Comment: also, try using the no conflict mode or just jQuery('selector') way